# How to get <td value="1">.value (should be 1 in a string )

Tags: javascript, html, null

My file which is called 'table.htm' (trying to make a table) is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-AU">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var thOne = document.getElementById("thOne");
alert(thOne)
//thOne.innerHTML = String(thOne.value);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="trOne">
<th value="1" id="thOne">
</th>
<td value="" id="tdOne">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It shouldn't alert null, but it does.
The commented out line should set id("thOne").innerHTML to it's value (1 in a string) but instead says it does not have a value (as TypeError). I know that, but how do I set the innerHTML to '1'?

Comment: your script is running before the body is loaded, therefore that element doesn't yet exist - try moving the script to just above `</body>`

Comment: Why does a td have a value? use a data attribute.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-AU">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="trOne" style="font-family: Arial, cursive;/* display: block; */width: 640px; height: 240px; left: ; top: 100%;">
<th id="thOne" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
<script type="text/javascript" style="display: none;">
var thOne = document.getElementById("thOne");
thOne.innerHTML = '<p id="thOneContent">1</p>';
</script>
</th>
<td id="tdOne" style="display: block;">
<div id="tdContent"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element after body `loaded`.
e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-AU">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function bodyLoad() {
    var thOne = document.getElementById("thOne");
    var value = thOne.getAttribute('value');
    alert("value is " + value);
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="bodyLoad()">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="trOne">
        <th value="1" id="thOne">
        </th>
        <td value="" id="tdOne">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```